# Confusion using pipe and reg add for modifying registry value

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-registry

I am trying to create a command line command that will edit a registry value. However, the value I need to insert is very long, and comes from a file rather than a single number. I tried using the pipe to read the contents of the file, then send it as an input to the `reg add` command, but that doesn't seem to be right.

The following command results in setting the registry value to zero (which is not expected, because the file I'm reading from is not empty):

```
type saved_game.xml | reg add "key name" /v "SaveGame1_h1867918427" /t REG_BINARY /f
```

The following command results in `Invalid syntax` error:

```
type saved_game.xml | reg add "key name" /v "SaveGame1_h1867918427" /t REG_BINARY /f /d
```

where "key name" is the name of an actual key, just deleted it here for privacy.

Thanks

Comment: Is the data binary, or strring? REG_BINARY might be issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't understand what you mean. Aren't all files made of binary data? How would I turn a text file like .xml into a state that would be interpreted as binary?

Comment: See https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/registry-data-types

Comment: What about the second half of my comment, how do I turn the file into something acceptable as binary data? @DrMoishePippik I can convert the text into its hex equivilant but if I paste that back into a file, it seems to be just textual representation of those numbers, not binary data

Comment: I just tried putting the hex code into a text file, but the results are exactly the same

Comment: I think `/d` requires an option-argument (it's a POSIX term, I don't know Windows terminology). You tagged `bash`. In Bash one could use command substitution to solve a similar problem. Is your shell really Bash? After seeing few examples I guess `/d` expects a string containing hexadecimal digits, not raw binary data; does `saved_game.xml` contain such string? Side note: I'm amazed how Windows [managed to complicate things](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/why-the-windows-registry-sucks-technically/) that in \*nix consist of manipulating files.

Comment: What do you mean by "putting hex in a text file"? Did you copy hex data and save it as txt/xml? What is also the exact goal here? Edit the question and specify how the outcome should look (binary, string, doesn't matter) and how long the data exactly is rather than just listing what you're trying to do.